# Error when starting Couchdb

Tags: couchdb

I am using MacOS and installed couchdd using homebrew. I was able to run it successfully but when i changed the bind_address it seemed to have stopped working.I tried to change that setting on .ini files and also tried unistalling and re-installing but still in vain.
Here is the error i am getting

```
Apache CouchDB 1.2.0 (LogLevel=info) is starting.
[error] [<0.92.0>] {error_report,<0.30.0>,
                       {<0.92.0>,supervisor_report,
                        [{supervisor,{local,couch_secondary_services}},
                         {errorContext,start_error},
                         {reason,
                             {'EXIT',
                                 {{badmatch,{error,einval}},
                                  [{mochiweb_socket_server,parse_options,2,
                                       [{file,"mochiweb_socket_server.erl"},
                                        {line,91}]},
                                   {mochiweb_socket_server,start,1,
                                       [{file,"mochiweb_socket_server.erl"},
                                        {line,39}]},
                                   {couch_httpd,start_link,2,
                                       [{file,"couch_httpd.erl"},{line,148}]},
                                   {supervisor,do_start_child,2,
                                       [{file,"supervisor.erl"},{line,303}]},
                                   {supervisor,start_children,3,
                                       [{file,"supervisor.erl"},{line,287}]},
                                   {supervisor,init_children,2,
                                       [{file,"supervisor.erl"},{line,253}]},
                                   {gen_server,init_it,6,
                                       [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,304}]},
                                   {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
                                       [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,227}]}]}}},
                         {offender,
                             [{pid,undefined},
                              {name,httpd},
                              {mfargs,{couch_httpd,start_link,[]}},
                              {restart_type,permanent},
                              {shutdown,brutal_kill},
                              {child_type,worker}]}]}}
{"init terminating in do_boot",{{badmatch,{error,{bad_return,{{couch_app,start,[normal,["/usr/local/etc/couchdb/default.ini","/usr/local/etc/couchdb/local.ini"]]},{'EXIT',{{badmatch,{error,shutdown}},[{couch_server_sup,start_server,1,[{file,"couch_server_sup.erl"},{line,98}]},{application_master,start_it_old,4,[{file,"application_master.erl"},{line,274}]}]}}}}}},[{couch,start,0,[{file,"couch.erl"},{line,18}]},{init,start_it,1,[]},{init,start_em,1,[]}]}}
```

Comment: Looks like a syntax error in one of your .ini files. Check for that, or post them here.

Comment: I think that you can read this reference:
https://serverfault.com/questions/735760/increment-couchdb-concurrent-connections/742269